# Looks like favorite count status update is wrong

Tags: bug, bookmarks

Edit: Duplicate of [Why does my favorite count vary on my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190521/why-does-my-favorite-count-vary-on-my-profile) on MetaSE.

But I still contend it's an (itsy-bitsy) bug:

- [Joel says](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/fog0000000249.html), "A user interface is well-designed when the program behaves exactly how the user thought it would."
- This part of the SE UI is, therefore, not well-designed.

So... when will it be fixed? A fix could be a change to the `title` so that the hover text reports the meaning of the bubble.

---

I have 7 favourite questions on MetaSO. I was alerted to this by being shown that I had 111 new favourite changes (or whatever the blue number is supposed to mean).

[image]

Looks like a bug.

Comment: Does that not represent the number of activities since your last visit to the tab?  Must have been a lot of answers/edits.  I thought that was what that number represented.

Comment: The hover text didn't say that. (I didn't screen-grab it.) If that is what it means, great!

Comment: UberMeta dupes (this is an SE Network issue, not just SO): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190521/248731, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82616/248731

Comment: It looks like the number in the tab is in binary, and the number in the header in decimal.

Comment: BTW, your favorite list is public data.

Comment: @Braiam - I figured I could avoid people taking the discussion off topic if I blurred them... apparently not! 8^)

Comment: So what functionality elsewhere makes you think this is a bug? The "responses" tab shows how many responses people have made to you- When there have been new responses since the last time you looked at the tab, the little blue number pops up and counts them. There were changes to your favorited questions here since the last time  you opened that tab- Why would it not work the same way and keep count of the changes? Reputation (on main) is also the same way- It keeps track of the reputations changes since you last checked the tab- Should the indicator instead show your current rep?

Comment: In otherwords to fix this "bug" as you contend that it is, you would have to make the UI inconsistent. That would only serve to make other users believe the _other_ tabs on the page are not working they way they should, _or_ it would lead them to believe the new behavior of the notification bubble on the favorites tab is a bug.

Comment: @kendra Nope, it already is inconsistent. The fix is to make it consistent. The "reputation" tab's `title` is "reputation you have earned", and its blue bubble shows the reputation earned since you last looked. The "responses" tab's title is "your recent responses", and bb shows the # responses since you last looked. _Inconsistently_, the `title` on the "favorites" tab is "questions you have favorited", but the bb __does not__ show the change in # of questions favorited. Better `title`: "changes in your favorite questions".

Comment: @Mogsdad The "title" elements tell you what _that tab_ is there for, not what the bubbles are there for. So, actually, it is consistent in that regard. The bubbles _always_ show the changes associated with what is in that tab (rep gained since last look, responses since last look, question activity since last look), and the titles tell you want to expect in those tabs regardless of the bubble being there. The title would be wrong if there were no changes should it be "changes in your favorite questions" all the time. (cont.)

Comment: I _could_ see a title change to "There are changes to your favorited questions." when the blue bubble is shown, and changing back when the bubble has been cleared. However, I'm not sure how worth developer time this particular change is.

Comment: Yeah, low value possibly. Three dup reports on it, though, so the sort of thing to think about if & when any redesign occurs, since it's not as cut & dry as one might want. I'm not in the position to decide what gets fixed when - just to report & discuss.

Comment: "So... when will it be fixed?" [6-8 weeks is the current turnaround time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514).

Comment: Seems like the 6-8wk estimation was a little bit optimistic :p

Comment: Still repros. I just favorited 2 questions on MetaSO and received notification of "20" new favorites.